# Protocol with "where" causes crash

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I want to use `Protocol` to hide type of classes which is subclass of `UIViewController`. So I create a `Protocol` looks like this:

```swift
protocol Displayable where Self: UIViewController {
    func display()
}
```

and the concrete class:

```swift
class DisplayableViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension DisplayableViewController: Displayable {
    func display() {
        _ = view
    }
}
```

Everything goes well, until I perfom `display()` at runtime:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var displayable: Displayable!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayable = DisplayableViewController()
        displayable.display()
    }
}
```

Crashes occurs at `_ = view`.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

---

Remove `where Self: UIViewController` or make `(displayable as? DisplayableViewController).display()` solve this problem, but why?

And I just want subclass of UIViewController to conform it.

Here is the [demo](https://github.com/ingocraft/ProtocolCauseCrashDemo) to reproduce it.

Swift version: 4.2

Comment: your demo project has missing files – it cannot be even compiled.

Comment: Update to Swift 5.0 and replace `where Self: UIViewController` by `: UIViewController` maybe works

Comment: @holex fixed, check it please.

Comment: @J.Doe any idea for Swift 4.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your type a composite of `UIViewController` and `Displayable`.

For example:

```
private var displayable: (UIViewController & Displayable)!
```

---

Here is a link to some docs that contain relevant info on composite types:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html

Comment: wow, it works, thank you.
Can you provide references or keywords for more detail.
I have never known this feature of Swift.

Comment: [Protocol Composition Type] (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html)